# archiver/publisher for external artifact URL

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow

I'm generating a presigned S3 URL as part of a workflow job, which is passed into a build step that essentially runs outside of the workspace (via ssh).  I've been unable to identify an existing publish or archive plugin (workflow compatible or not) that will allow setting an external URL.  Is there a plugin or workaround that enables setting a URL as an artifact or the addition of simple metadata to the build results?

I'm a bit surprised that there isn't a way to publish metadata directly from a workflow -- it seems like this would be insanely useful functionally.  Have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

[JENKINS-26918](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26918) proposes support for some of the features in the Groovy Postbuild plugin. Using core Workflow, you can call

```
currentBuild.description = "<a href=\"${url}\">Published</a>"
```

(or whatever your installation’s markup formatter allows).

Comment: I apparently missed the memo on `currentBuild` -- Iet me see if that will work for me.